# HTTP Error Handling Best Practices iOS

Tags: ios, networking, error-handling, httpresponse, nserror

Currently working on the network part of an iOS App. I'm struggling with the Error Handling.

Lets take a simple example: doing a Login Request. *(I'm using **NSURLRequest** with an **NSURLSessionDelegate**)*
In most of the cases, I'll get either a 200 statusCode, or either a 401 statusCode in the response of the request. Here, no NSError.
But I can as well, get another **HTTP StatusCode** (such as 500 Internal Server Error). Or, I can also get an **NSError**, like the Request has been canceled, No Internet connection or whatever.

My question is: What if I transform those wrong **Http StatusCode** to a proper **custom NSError**. So, it will be easier in my controller side to switch case this error and react properly.
Instead of first catching the error, react. Then, check the statusCode, react.

By this way, I would be able to generalize the **error handling** to all my network requests. "Receive a 401 status Code ? just Log out the user"
"If No error, the request just worked well".

This model could works, but not in all the cases. This time I just didn't format the email correctly in the Login form. The server will provide me a 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code. But I still need to get the **body** of this **request** to know which field I formatted wrong.

What is the **best practices** to handle those cases ?